# Escape Object's property value quotes dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

Summary: 
I'm getting data from backend. Purpose is to dynamically parse forms with validations

Issue:
My validation accessors are returned as string, I need them to be Classes.

Question: How to escape quotation marks dynamically? (Dynamically, because I'm getting an array of validation objects)

What I'm getting:

[image: What I'm getting]

What I need:

[image: What I need]

Comment: Please add your actual code.

Comment: try to use eval. you will have to loop and remove quotes using eval. Please try this

Comment: there are several ways to achieve what you need, it will be easier to help if you add a code sample that generate your output

Comment: @JackBashford can't upload actual code, because it's a big project, code which manipulates validations is scattered through 10 services

Comment: @pawankumar eval didn't work, it returned ReferenceError: Validators is not defined